# Deadlock when closing sqlite database

Tags: rx-java, deadlock, android-room, sqlcipher, commonsware-cwac

I'm investigating occassinal ANR in my project. It happens when there are a lot of requests to database in the background, user clicks button and database is being closed as a part of logout. I'm using saferoom and rx-java2.

Here is some code from test project, on which I tried to reproduce issue.(reproduces ~30% of time):

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TestDb
    private val disposables = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        openStorage("password")

        val d = Observable.interval(100, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
            .map { db.testDao().insert(TestEntity()) }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ status.text = "WRITING" }, {})
        disposables.add(d)

        closeDbButton.setOnClickListener {
            disposables.clear()
            db.close()
            status.text = "DB CLOSED"
        }
    }

    @Synchronized
    fun openStorage(storageSecret: String) {
        val factory = SafeHelperFactory(storageSecret.toCharArray())
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(this, TestDb::class.java, TestDb.DATABASE_NAME)
            .openHelperFactory(factory)
            .build()
    }
}
```

As you can see, to emulate the issue I'm trying to access database in the loop and at the same time closing database. Even though I dispose writing chain before closing, deadlock happens and app freezes.

I also tried to analyse thread dump:

```
"main" prio=5 tid=1 Waiting
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x727565f0 self=0x7b42cbea00
  | sysTid=24431 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7bc78e99a8
  | state=S schedstat=( 3718987857 647207377 6247 ) utm=336 stm=34 core=3 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7fd4c9a000-0x7fd4c9c000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes=
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
  - waiting on <0x017bb93d> (a java.lang.Object)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2137)
  - locked <0x017bb93d> (a java.lang.Object)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:358)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:868)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:900)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1223)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$FairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:225)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:286)
  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:553)
  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.close(SQLiteDatabase.java:1284)
  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.close(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:272)
  - locked <0x064ca532> (a com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper$1)
  at com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper$OpenHelper.close(Helper.java:202)
  - locked <0x064ca532> (a com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper$1)
  at com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper.close(Helper.java:146)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.close(RoomDatabase.java:189)
  at com.company.deadlocktest.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:38)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)


"RxComputationThreadPool-1" daemon prio=5 tid=15 Blocked
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12fc0610 self=0x7b3a839c00
  | sysTid=24450 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b2c5384f0
  | state=S schedstat=( 2462204096 250602566 3746 ) utm=209 stm=36 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0x7b2c436000-0x7b2c438000 stackSize=1037KB
  | held mutexes=
  at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:-1)
  - waiting to lock <0x064ca532> (a com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper$1) held by thread 1
  at com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(Helper.java:158)
  at com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper.getWritableDatabase(Helper.java:120)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful(RoomDatabase.java:286)
  at com.company.deadlocktest.TestDao_Impl.insert(TestDao_Impl.java:49)
  at com.company.deadlocktest.MainActivity$onCreate$d$1.apply(MainActivity.kt:30)
  at com.company.deadlocktest.MainActivity$onCreate$d$1.apply(MainActivity.kt:18)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableMap$MapObserver.onNext(ObservableMap.java:59)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableInterval$IntervalObserver.run(ObservableInterval.java:83)
  at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.run(ScheduledDirectPeriodicTask.java:38)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:307)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:302)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

As you can see Rx thread is blocked by lock, acquired by main thread (`<0x064ca532> com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper$1`), and main thread is in WAIT state.

So I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to avoid this issue or this is some kind of bug in saferoom / sqlcipher.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no RxJava expert, but I don't think the threading effects of `clear()` will happen instantaneously.

In terms of a workaround, don't call `close()` on the main application thread. Usually, we don't `close()` at all, as we never know when is a good time, given everything that is going on in the app. If you really want to `close()`, then do so on the `Schedulers.io()` thread that you are using for your database access.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I need to close database as I want it to be inaccessible due to user logout. With your workaround a need to make all database requests from single thread, right?

Comment: @mol: Yes, or otherwise make sure that nothing is accessing the database at the time that you want to close it. For example, if you initiate a query *after* you close the database, even if both of those things are done on the main application thread, the query will throw an error complaining about a closed database.

Comment: It is okay to get an exception if you're trying to access db after closing, but ANR seems like a buggy behaviour to me. And I don't see how it is possible in a production app to access database from a single thread. But thanks anyway.